# Laravel image paths from controller to view

Tags: php, laravel

My image's path is `public/uploads/users/image.png` then using `src` like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/users/image.png') }}" />
```

But for every user the image has to be changed.

I pass the image name of the user from controller as something like this

```
foreach ($user as $key) {
                $this->data['user_img'] = $key->avatar;
            }
```

Here, I have to change the user image as per `$user_img` from controller

How should I give it in the `src` of image tag.

I tried like this way

```
src="{{ asset('uploads/users/"{{$user_img}}"')}}"
```

But it seems to be an error for me.How should I resole this.

Somebody help me.

Comment: The stuff within `{{ }}` is normal PHP. The way you tried is like doing `<?php <?php $user_img ?> ?>` - it'll cause syntax errors.

Comment: First of all: `{{ asset('uploads/users/"{{$user_img}}"')}}` is wrong as it has nested `{{ }}`. Secondly, can you enlighten us with the contents of `$user_img` or how you set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this method for image in laravel.

if this is your image path **public/assets/uploads/users/image.png**.

image in **$user_img**

```
{{asset('assets/uploads/users').'/'.$user_img}}
```

Or we can use

```
{{ asset('assets/uploads/users') }}/{{$user_img}}
```

Comment: `asset()` looks in the `public` folder for the given asset.

Comment: yes asset() looks in public folder and then we can use next folder for image path.

Comment: I tried this..It works for meeee :D..But instead of `{{asset('assets/uploads/users').'/'.$user_img}}` I gave it as `{{asset('uploads/users').'/'.$user_img}}` which leads to the correct path.. :) Thank you so much

Comment: Since my image path is `public/uploads/users/image.png`

Comment: you dont have **assets** folder in **public**  so your method is working .  :)

Comment: Yes.. :) Thank you once again.. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/users/' . $user_img) }}"/>
```

If that doesn't work the problem is not with the asset helper function but presumably in the value `$user_img` gets (or doesn't get..)

Comment: Thank you Ben but `$user_img` gets the correct image.But I dont know why your code was not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `laravelcollective/html`, try this:

```
{{ Html::image('public/uploads/users/'.$user_img) }}
```

By the way, did you pass the `$user_img` to the `view` from `controller` ?

Answer (score 1):

Excellent answer as it is a multi-fault protection

```
 src="{{ asset('uploads/users/'.$user_img")}}"
```

and can use

```
{{asset('uploads/users').'/'.$user_img}}
```

> > > other answer.... is scsesfual

Answer (score 0):

try

```
src="{{ asset(\'uploads/users/$user_img\')}}"
```

Comment: It results in the `src` like `uploads/users/$user_img`

Comment: and this `src='{{ asset("uploads/users/$user_img")}}'`

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('assets/images/'.$user_img)}}"/>
```

Use Laravel Collective HTML Package
After installed this package you can use like this

```
{!! Html::style('your/css/file.css') !!}
{!! Html::script('your/js/file.js') !!}
{!! Html::image('your/image/file.jpg') !!}
```

Comment: Which is same as Alexey Mezenin code..But It doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,

I can't understand why its not working for me.

But the `$user_img` retrieve the exact image name.

Then finally I tried like this way.

In controller

```
foreach ($user as $key) {
    $this->data['user_img'] = \URL::to('').'/uploads/users/'.$key->avatar;
}
```

And in my View I just call the `$user_img` in the `src`

```
src="{{$user_img}}"
```

**Edit**

By using 
**Shrikant Bhardwaj** code I gave it as

```
{{asset('uploads/users').'/'.$user_img}}
```

Thank you. :)